# Is there any way to pass data from one sub domain to another subdomain opens in 2 different tabs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 1st sub-domain eg. a.xyz.com and trying to pass data to 2nd subdomain eg. b.xyz.com which is under domain eg. xyz.com..

I have tried using local storage , session storage and cookies, but not able to pass.
Is there any solution to pass data from first sub-domain to second sub-domain
my example uses React js

Comment: please do not repeat text to get past the question checks. instead add a text-based [mcve] of what you've tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following way to pass the data:

**1. Query Parameters:** You can pass data between subdomains using query parameters in the URL. For example, you can append the data as part of the URL when navigating from the first subdomain to the second subdomain.

**2. Shared Backend/API:** If the first and second subdomains share a common backend or API, you can store the data on the server-side and retrieve it in the second subdomain by making a request to the server.